# How to decrypt this file?

Tags: debuggers, encryption, visual-basic

I have to decrypt a file that is used by an app built using VB5. The file itself contains some data that is decrypted when the app is run and the decrypted data is text data that is displayed in a listview.

I have seen that the app decrypts each character one by one. I think the decryption algorithm is some kind of bit shifting where each character is converted to binary and depending on the length of the binary it does some operation.

For example

```
Encrypted character # 

Decrypted Character 1

"#" in ascii, 35 = 10 0011

"1" in ascii, 49 = 11 0001

encrypted: 178 = 10 11 00 10
decrypted:  83 = 1  01 00 11
```

The full encrypted file can be found [here](https://mega.co.nz/#!rQhnVIAb!tsuwN8P5Ihp-ftNCdq2tHweWrLjkLAl6YG5MfvlU4XY).

So far I have seen two methods to get the contents:

1. Decrypt the file
2. Read the memory of the app when it is run.

Any help/comment is most welcome.

Comment: looks like binary encryption ,i ever seen which looks like that